# Add more than one formula in SharePoint Column validation

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, column-validation

I am struggling to add two formula together in SharePoint list column validation.

For example :

```
= formula 1 AND formula 2 (didn't work) ;
= formula1,formula2(didn't work)
```

Can anybody give some light?

Answer (score 1):

It has to be in below format for logical operations AND and OR

Column 1 - 15
Column 2 - 9
Column 3 - 8

```
    =AND([Column1]>[Column2], [Column1]<[Column3]) - Is 15 greater than 9 and less than 8? 
Value -(No)

    =IF(AND([Column1]>[Column2], [Column1]<[Column3]), "OK", "Not OK") - If 15 is greater than 9 and less than 8, return "OK". 
    Value - (Not OK)
```

Comment: Hi Siddharths,
Please read my question , this is not my requirement , I dont have any conditional formula. I have two different formula, both need to be applied on that column, and it is not dependent on any column.

Comment: I think his first example covers what your question was `=AND(<condition1>, <condition2>)`

Comment: @baxD...I understood the question... there is nothing like 2 formula... you have to first check your first formula logic in condition 1 and if that is true check for 2nd formula in 2nd condition..in fact you can do nested if and create n number of formulas... but using above syntax...still if you have doubt edit question with details on what your formula looks like..

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the formulas (maybe there are problems in them) I can only suggest to put them in brackets. Following your example, it should be:

```
=(formula 1) AND (formula 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/and-function-78956048-53c7-484a-ab0b-6e70d7f03400) or [OR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/or-function-9a2a1cca-696f-4d19-a959-3943babd076f) to add two formulas together, choose one as your requirement.

If you are not sure, you can provide the two detail formulas and requirement.